# Google Maps Api returns ZERO RESULT

Tags: c#, google-maps, geocoding

I am using Google Maps API in my project and I have problem. When I try to convert lat lon to city and I have few objects everything is all right. When I  a lot of objects some of object are converted successfully, but some returns ZERO RESULT but when I try to convert all objects second time some objects with ZERO RESULT in first attempt are converted successfully in second attempt. Also when I copy link which return ZERO RESULT and put it in browser Google shows correct XML result.

Can anyone help me?

Code:

```
    private void abc(string City)  // translating lat lon to City and shows it on map
    {
        if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() == true)
        {
            String Address = String.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={0}&sensor=false", City);
            WebClient webClientCity = new WebClient();
            webClientCity.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClientCity_OpenReadCompleted);
            webClientCity.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(Address));
        }
    }

    private void webClientCity_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Pushpin pushpin1;
        Location a1 = new Location();
        XMLParserCity _Cparser;
        _Cparser = XMLParserCity.Instance;
        try
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(e.Result))
            {
                string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                if (data != null)
                {
                    _Cparser.DataToParse = data;
                    _Cparser.ParseStateData();
                }
                foreach (geometry st in _Cparser.CStateCollection)
                {
                    pushpin1 = new Pushpin() { Tag = "pushpin" };
                    a1.Latitude = st.lat;
                    a1.Longitude = st.lng;
                    pushpin1.Template = null;
                    pushpin1.Content = new Ellipse()
                    {
                        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
                        Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                        StrokeThickness = 4,
                        Opacity = .8,
                        Height = 25,
                        Width = 25
                    };
                    MapLayer.SetPosition(pushpin1, a1);
                    map1.Children.Add(pushpin1);
                    a1.Latitude = st.lat;
                    a1.Longitude = st.lng;
                    location.Add(a1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception bl)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(bl.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

"ZERO_RESULTS" indicates that the geocode was successful but returned no results. This may occur if the geocoder was passed a non-existent address. Try with some static address and check.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and results are the same. In first attempt return ZERO RESULT and in another attempt return successfull result.